# If values of two sheets match then add new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets that have two columns with equal values, I want my script when the two values match create a new sheet with the name of value in a second column of the second sheet adjacent to the value found.

The script below stops at the first matching, I wish that the process continues for all possible matches.

[image: The sheets and the tables are so structured:]

```
 Public Sub try()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, b As Long, Fente As String, newente As Worksheet
    With Worksheets("totale")
      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 2 To lastRow

       With Worksheets("totale")
           If .Cells(i, 5).Value = Worksheets("liste").Cells(i, 2).Value Then
             Fente = Worksheets("liste").Cells(i, 1).Value
             Set newente = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
             newente.Name = Fente

             i = i + 1
           End If
       End With
    Next i      
 End Sub
```

Comment: you have to move the i = i + 1 outside of the If

Comment: i tried but the loop always stop with the first match and add only one sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works almost OK there is one issue but not as you describe it the issue that I noticed is that you manually increment i which will result in i=i+2 when match is found and next line **will not be checked** as it will skip every second line when matched.

I believe the problem is that you might look at wrong records when determining end value of loop or pointing to incorrect columns/sheets for names. Your last row procedure check "Totale" column A but the values you compare are column "B" in "Liste" and column "E" in totale and creates a sheet based on name in "Liste" column "A". If that is incorrect you might need to change your pointers.

So your loop will repeat itself as many times as many records you have in Totale."A" end then stop, additionally you will get an error if Liste.A will be blank or will contain illegal character so I included additional check in the code below.

```
Public Sub try()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, b As Long, Fente As String, newente As Worksheet

With Worksheets("totale")
   lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 2 To lastRow

   With Worksheets("totale")
       If .Cells(i, 5).Value = Worksheets("liste").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            Fente = Worksheets("liste").Cells(i, 1).Value
            Set newente = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
            'check if name is valid and not empty cell
            If FileNameValid(Fente) And Fente <> "" Then
                newente.Name = Fente
            Else
            'if not save as illegal name
                newente.Name = "bad_name_row_" & i
            End If
            'i = i + 1  - REMOVE THIS PART. You skip additional line when they are the same
            '              this is executed and then Next i also increments by one
        End If
End With
Next i

End Sub

'check if valid file name is used in cell
Function FileNameValid(sFileName As String) As Boolean
Dim notAllowed As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim result As Boolean
'list of forbidden characters
notAllowed = Array("/", "\", ":", "*", "?", "&lt; ", ">", "|", """")
'Initial result = OK
result = True
For i = LBound(notAllowed) To UBound(notAllowed)
    If InStr(1, sFileName, notAllowed(i)) > 0 Then
    'forbidden character used
        result = False

        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
FileNameValid = result
End Function
```

### UPDATE

With the screens you just added it is certain that you point to wrong cells in macro. Swapping those pointers and removing that i+1 should do it.
`Cells(i, 5).Value = Worksheets("liste").Cells(i, **1**).Value Then
                Fente = Worksheets("liste").Cells(i, **2**).Value`

Try the full updated code from above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub try()
Dim lastRow As Long, lrow As Long
Dim i As Long, c As Long, Fente As String, newente As Worksheet

With Worksheets("totale")
   lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
End With
With Worksheets("liste")
   lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 2 To lastRow
For c = 2 To lrow

   With Worksheets("totale")
       If .Cells(i, 5).Value = Worksheets("liste").Cells(i, 2).Value Then
            Fente = Worksheets("liste").Cells(c, 1).Value
            'skip to next value if sheet exists
            If sheetExists(Fente) = True Then
                On Error Resume Next
            Else
                Set newente = ThisWorkbook.sheets.Add(After:= _
                ThisWorkbook.sheets(ThisWorkbook.sheets.Count))
                If FileNameValid(Fente) And Fente <> "" Then
                    newente.Name = Fente
                Else
                'if not save as illegal name
                    newente.Name = "bad_name_row_" & i
                End If
            'NOTE: this will overwrite name set by ELSE
            newente.Name = Fente

            End If
       End If
       End With
       Next c
       Next i
End Sub

'check if valid file name is used in cell
Function FileNameValid(sFileName As String) As Boolean
Dim notAllowed As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim result As Boolean
'list of forbidden characters
notAllowed = Array("/", "\", ":", "*", "?", "&lt; ", ">", "|", """")
'Initial result = OK
result = True
For i = LBound(notAllowed) To UBound(notAllowed)
    If InStr(1, sFileName, notAllowed(i)) > 0 Then
    'forbidden character used
        result = False
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
FileNameValid = result
End Function

Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet
End Function
```

Thank you all.

Comment: In the line before two End Ifs you have the  `newente.Name = Fente`. If the else statement set the name of sheet to bad_name_row_i this will be overwritten. Additionally as the name was invalid it will result in run time error. You can remove that line as the IF statement above will assign this or the bad name or move that line to your IF case before Else. Best way would be to simply keep it as:
`If (FileNameValid(Fente) And Fente <> "") OR sheetExists(Fente)  Then` so your above IF ELSE can be also removed.