# Vba Excel - if value = value filtering and copy on corect sheet - speed up

Tags: vba, excel

I need some advice.
my code Check the cell "E" in sheet "Total" with the cell "B" in sheet "lists", if the values are equal it reads the cell "A" in the sheet "list" (which contains the name of all my sheets), and copies the match line in the correct sheet.

My script works but is very slow. Do you have any advice on how to speed up the process?

Currently the script read and copy line by line, I thought to speed up the process by applying automatic filter but do not know where to start ...
Thanks in advance.

This is my actual script:

```
Sub copystatus()

  Dim LR As Long
  Dim LC As Integer
  Dim LB As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim ws3 As Worksheet
  Dim cLista As String

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.sheets("totale")
  Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.sheets("liste")

  LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
  LC = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

  With ws
     For x = 2 To LR
     For i = 2 To LC

     If .Cells(x, 5).value = ws2.Cells(i, 2).value Then
     cLista = ws2.Cells(i, 1).value
     Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.sheets(cLista)
     On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
     LB = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     ws3.Rows(LB + 1).value = .Rows(x).value
     ws3.Rows(1).value = .Rows(1).value
     End If

     Next i
     Next x

  End With 

ErrorHandler:

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out - the increase should be visible:

```
Sub copystatus()

    Dim LR As Long
    Dim LC As Integer
    Dim LB As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim cLista As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False


    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.sheets("totale")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.sheets("liste")

    LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws
    For x = 2 To LR
        For i = 2 To LC

        If .Cells(x, 5).value = ws2.Cells(i, 2).value Then
            cLista = ws2.Cells(i, 1).value
            Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.sheets(cLista)
            On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            LB = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ws3.Rows(LB + 1).value = .Rows(x).value
            ws3.Rows(1).value = .Rows(1).value
        End If

        Next i
    Next x

    End With 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

ErrorHandler:

End Sub
```

And at the end set the ws, ws2, ws3 to Nothing like this:
Set ws = nothing
set ws2 = nothing

Comment: I applied the changes you suggested but unfortunately I do not see any improvement in execution speed.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you copy my code? With absolute no improvement in the speed?

Comment: @Ruif0 disabling screen updating should definitely speed it up.
How many record you have in each of those worksheets (values of LR and LC)?

Comment: Turn off calculation and use arrays rather than the range maybe?

Comment: Or if you want to go even further, change the "Integer" value to "Long", it would be some milliseconds faster.

Comment: pav LR is 783 rows and 59 rows LC. This script is always part of the previous project.<br/> 

ok pav and Vityata, I applied all your advice to my code and it runs faster, thanks a lot!<br/> 

@Nathan_Sav I use vba to be very few time and the use of the array generates a lot of confusion to me ... Could you give me an example of how to convert my code with the Array? Thanks so much.<br/>

Comment: You don't need to set the worksheet objects to nothing. [See this explanation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/).

Comment: @Comintern, thanks for the article. However, for me the simple rule - "Set to something - Set to nothing" must be followed in VBA. Otherwise one should start thinking in which scope the objects are and if it was declared as a global object, you would have problems.

Comment: On should *always* think about object scope, and use the narrowest possible scope possible. Setting global objects to Nothing is where you start running into problems, not the other way around.

Comment: @Comintern, if you read the comments below the article, you would get some good ideas. But anyhow, for me setting objects to nothing is a must have and a price I would like to pay.

Comment: Trust me, this was laid to rest ***years*** ago. Like the blog post says, it's pointless, so it shouldn't do active harm to include it - but I like my code to have a point.  In this instance, there is already code that sets the worksheet objects to nothing.  It's the line `End Sub`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, starting with a 2 column data set

[image]

```
Sub ARRAY_WAY()

Dim arrSource() As Variant
Dim arrCheck() As Variant
Dim intArrayLoop As Integer
Dim intArrayLoop2 As Integer

arrSource = Range("A1:B7").Value
arrCheck = Range("C1:D3").Value

For intArrayLoop = 1 To UBound(arrSource)

    For intArrayLoop2 = 1 To UBound(arrCheck)

        If arrCheck(intArrayLoop2, 1) = arrSource(intArrayLoop, 1) Then
            arrCheck(intArrayLoop2, 2) = arrSource(intArrayLoop, 2)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next intArrayLoop2

Next intArrayLoop

Range("c1:d3").Value = arrCheck

End Sub
```

Will give an output like this (Columns C to D)

[image]

Comment: i will try!! Thank you :D

Comment: Nice one. I always looped through ranges, this might be a better alternative for my future code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that is another follow-up macro [for your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655297/if-values-of-two-sheets-match-then-add-new-sheet/39656097#39656097)?
As you already check for that condition and generate your worksheets there (cLista) it would be better off to copy the rows there in the first place.
With screen updating disabled as suggested by Vityata this should be running OK.

You can try and simplify this part:

`Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.sheets(cLista)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
LB = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ws3.Rows(LB + 1).value = .Rows(x).value
ws3.Rows(1).value = .Rows(1).value`

You might be better off without using set for ws3 and just simply refer to your target in one line instead of doins multiple variable assignment

`sheets(clista).Rows(sheets(clista).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row +1).value = .Rows(x)value
sheets(clista).Rows(1).value = .Rows(1)value`